# Boolean in FOR loop

Tags: java, for-loop, boolean

I don't understand this code. One of my friend thought me to use the boolean to make it work. I don't really understand when he explains it. Why is the `found` in the `for` loop?

```
int id = input.nextInt();   
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < z && !found; i++){
    if (arr[i].getId() == id){
        found = true;
        index = i;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here "Boolean" is using to terminate the loop as soon as the inputted "id" found in your array. The good thing is the compiler don't have to search until last index wheres "id" already found.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional statement inside the for loop reads

```
i < z && !found
```

When 'found' is true, the for loop will stop looping. You can read more about for loops [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

For loop syntax looks like this:

```
for (initialize ; condition ; increment) {}
```

It's also possible to replace your for loop with a while loop.

```
int i = 0;
int found = false;
while(i < z && !found) {
    if(arr[i].getId()==id){
        found = true;
        index = i;
    }
}
```

In both cases, you can simplify your conditional using the "break" keyword. The break keyword causes a loop to exit *immediately*. This may or may not be the appropriate solution here, but it does show another way to handle these kinds of loops.

```
for(int i=0; i<z; i++){
    if(arr[i].getId()==id){
        index = i;
        break;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `i<z && !found` part of the for loop is the condition, which must be true in order for the loop to continue. Adding the `!found` part means that the loop would terminate when either `found` is true or `i>=z`, whichever happens first. Without that condition, the loop would always run `z` times, even if a match (i.e. `arr[i].getId()==id`) is found on the first iteration. Therefore, this condition is an optimization that reduces the running time of the loop.

An alternative to the `!found` condition is using the `break` keyword to terminate the loop :

```
            for(int i=0; i<z; i++){
                if(arr[i].getId()==id){
                    found = true;
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }   
            }
```

Comment: Thankyou so much Sir Eran ! it was really confusing at first. Didnt know what was the purpose of the found in the for loop. You made it clearer now . HAHA *weeeee* !